# How to find a time 7 days after now?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I have this table named "schedule" with Model's named also "schedule". Every schedule had their own `DateOfSchedule`. I want to ask how to display into this table schedule only schedule for today and 7 days before today and 7 days after today.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var viewModel = new ScheduleViewModel();    
viewModel.schedule = db.schedule.Where(
    x.DateOfSchedule.Year == DateTime.Now.Year &&
    x.DateOfSchedule.Month == DateTime.Now.Year &&
    x.DateOfSchedule.Day <= DateTime.Now.Year
).ToList();
```

Comment: try this x.DateOfSchedule <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(7) && x.DateOfSchedule >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)

Comment: Your `Where` needs a lambda expression - you can't have `.Where(x.y == z)` but you can have `.Where(x => x.y == z)` as `x` isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion. Note: use Date part to ignore time

```
viewModel.schedule = db.schedule.Where(x=> x.DateOfSchedule.Date >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7) 
   && x.DateOfSchedule.Date <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(7)).ToList();
```

Comment: DateTime.Today is more concise than the equivalent DateTime.Now.Date

Comment: @Joe yes it is an option.

Answer (score 0):

```
var viewModel = new ScheduleViewModel();    
viewModel.schedule = db.schedule.Where(x.DateOfScheduled > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) && x.DateOfScheduled <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

you can code....

```
var viewModel = new ScheduleViewModel();    
viewModel.schedule = db.schedule.Where( x =>
    Math.Abs((x.DateOfSchedule - DateTime.Now).TotalDays) <= 7).ToList();
```